# Trouble creating a Sharepoint Online site with template: Dependency feature 'PublishingSite' error

Tags: templates, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, wsp

Sharepoint online | create site with site Template  | Dependency feature PublishingSite for feature ' is not activated at this scope.

Hi,
I had created a site template .wsp from the sharepoint online site, I had recently created,
Now i am trying to create de production ambient with this template but when I was trying to activate this error occurred:

`Dependency feature 'PublishingSite' (id: f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa) for feature '1WebTemplate' (id: 69cee85e-59ee-45c2-86de-60777d438d97) is not activated at this scope.`

Image time line:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oviug.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7JtW.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNCSh.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jS4p.png

Can anyone help me? thnks